# What is the population of Bajor?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

How many people live on Bajor at the beginning of the Star Trek: Deep Space 9?

Memory Alpha mentions the population was "decimated" under the Cardassians, but that is a figure of speech; so, I'm also interested in the size of its population right before the occupation, and perhaps when Bajor started launching spaceships, in the 16th century BCE IIANM.

Comment: Remember that “decimated” literally means that one in ten was killed. It’s not a dramatic population collapse.

Comment: @MikeScott: The Merriam-Webster dictionary [suggests](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decimate) it can also mean "to reduce drastically especially in number".

Comment: @MikeScott [That might have been the ethymological origin of the term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimation_(Roman_army)), but nowadays it is not used like that, and certainly not in pop culture media. It is practically always used to mean "drastic reduction in number". And in the unlikely case that the author of the Memory Alpha article indeed meant the original Latin meaning of the term, then that would have meant a *systematic* execution of *exactly* every 10th Bajoran, which AFAIK did not happen in the background story of the show.

Comment: To be fair, losing 10% of a population is incredibly drastic. Consider the impact that the loss of 18 million lives in World War I - roughly 1% of world population at the time - had on the course of 20th century history.

Comment: @Izzy: The war was quite impactful, but I'm not sure we can say that it was the number of _deaths_ that had that impact. Also, deaths in a war (with a large number of the dead being soldiers) is different than deaths under an occupation.

Comment: @einpoklum About half the WWI deaths I cited were civilian, and I ignored the coincident Spanish Flu in the number I mentioned. Aside from which, I am simply pointing out that 10% (literal decimation) is a fantastically large number when talking about a world population. Though if you like, we could compare against the impact of the Holocaust - roughly the same number of deaths (~17 million), but later in the time line and thus a smaller percent of world population. Holocaust conditions were perhaps more in line with an "occupation".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [*Star Trek: Star Charts*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Star_Charts) factbook, the population of Bajor is **approximately 3.8 billion**.

[image]

According to Kira fifteen million Bajorans died during the 60 years of the Cardassian Occupation. This seems a surprisingly small death-toll given the damage the Cardassians are repeatedly stated to have caused to the planet's ecosystem.

> **KIRA:** *So you were wounded during an attack I carried out when I was part of the resistance, and I'm supposed to feel guilty? We were at war, Silaran. Fifteen million Bajorans died during the occupation and you want me to feel sorry for you?*
>
> <sub><sup>DS9: The Darkness And The Light</sup></sub>

Comment: 15 Million over 60 years means 250,000 a year, i.e. 0.0065% a year. That is indeed a rather mild occupation to be honest. Anyway, +1 and thanks.

Comment: While a good catch with the quote of 15 M, is there a way to attribute how it was calculated? Is it only the number of executions? Does it include people who dissappeared, died because of harsh working conditions or lack of medical facilities? Plus, 60 year occupation, that's a lot of time to cover your tracks.

Comment: @KMo - We only have Kira's word for it. Notably Ziyal was taught that it was closer to ten million in school.

Comment: TIL Dukat was right.

Comment: @einpoklum Your numbers are only remotely accurate if the population of Bajor had a zero growth rate for those 60s years. If they had population growth (e.g., Terra has added about 800,000,000 people over the past two decades), then the annual kill rate was *much* higher in the early years if the number of Bajorans killed was constant. Conversely, if the *rate* was constant, then the number of Bajorans killed increased proportional to the rate of population growth. Finally, if the kill rate & the absolute number of Bajorans both varied all bets are off. :) But good for trying math! :)

Comment: @KMo Considering that Kira is very biased against the Cardassian occupation, she would rather overstate the death toll than underestate it. Seems more like another case of [scifi writers not having a sense of scale](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ScifiWritersHaveNoSenseOfScale). They looked at 20th century Earth history, saw that a couple million is a reasonable death toll for an autoritarian empire and went with it without considering that interplanetary wars are several orders of magnitude larger than international wars.

Comment: @Lexible: I do assume zero growth rate. For a civilization which has been spacefaring for centuries, and didn't just industrialize, I think it's not unreasonable to assume they have reached a stable population size. Now, maybe Sol III added 800M people, but they are 400 years behind Bajor (by time-to-spaceflight); they had a nuclear semi-holocaust in the 21st century; and were now the center of a thriving semi-quadrant empire.